# Does a CSS3 animation still run when its display property is set to none?

Tags: css

I have a progressbar, which I animate using CSS while my page loads. After my page has finished loading, I set the progressbar's `display` property to `none` using Javascript, so  the page content will be displayed instead. The question is: Will the animation still run in the background while it's `display` property is set to `none`?

Comment: @GordonGekko I don't think this will make much of a difference, but I use the `animation` property and a `cubic-bezier`. My animation looks like this:
`animation: progressbar 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5) infinite;`

Comment: I honestly don't understand how this question is not clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **NO**. 
When you set element `display:none`, the animation stop. When the element `display: block` again, the animation start again at beginning point. 
See the example:

```js
let test1 = document.getElementById('test1');
let test2 = document.getElementById('test2');
let test3 = document.getElementById('test3');
setTimeout(() => {
  test1.style.display = 'none';
}, 1000)
setTimeout(() => {
  test1.style.display = 'block';
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
  test2.style.display = 'none';
}, 6000)
setTimeout(() => {
  test2.style.display = 'block';
}, 7000);

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  location.reload();
})
```

```css
.test {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #123;
  animation: test 4s;
}

#test2 {
  background-color: green
}

#test3 {
  background-color: blue
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    width: 30px
  }
  100% {
    width: 1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>div 1: 1s display none, 2s display block</div>
<div class="test" id="test1"> </div>
<div>div 2: 6s display none, 7s display block</div>
<div class="test" id="test2"> </div>
<div>div 3: no change</div>
<div class="test" id="test3"> </div>
<br>
<button id="btn">Reload</button>
```